# Domino Designer proxy server settings

Tags: proxy, xpages, lotus-domino, designer

I am trying to install an Eclipse plugin in Domino Designer. There are many useful tutorials how to do it. However, when I enter the remote site in the Application Locations window > Remote Location
http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/stable

```
I get this error code:

 CWPPR0031W: The requested provisioning operation(s) completed with partial success.
      Network connection problems encountered during search.
        Unable to access "http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/stable".
          Unable to access site: "http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/stable" [Server returned HTTP response code: "403 Forbidden"
```

My company uses a proxy server to access the internet. I suspect, the error is caused By Domino Designer trying to access the link directly. Is there any way to tell Designer to go through our proxy server?

Comment: Hi Csaba, do you find a solution for this problem

Comment: No, I gave up on it. I use Atlassian SourceTree, as others suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to install Mercurial into Domino Designer. I know in the past David Leedy and Declan Lynch had to install older versions, because Domino Designer is based on an older version of Eclipse. I'm not sure of the details for that. But I know both David and Declan now recommend using SourceTree for management of local mercurial source control repositories. It's better documented (several NotesIn9 episodes as well as Show 103 from Connect 2014 which I presented with Declan) and mor Domino developers use it (as well as non-Domino developers) so if you hit problems, there will be more of a cummunity to help.

Answer (score 1):

All of those settings will be handled by the location set in the Notes client.

Go to File>Preferences>Locations> and edit the current location

In the basics tab there is an option for proxy configuration. You should be able to drop in all of your configs right there.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I tried everything, I still get the 403 error.

Comment: Are your proxy settings handled on the OS or on the browser level?

Comment: I set the proxy script in Control Panel > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings > Use automatic configuration script

Comment: If your connection options are set at the OS level then they would not affect the application level. If you were setting the proxy settings on say IE then you would also need to set them on other applications. I don't think its a proxy issue.

Answer (score 0):

this site helps me to install a eclipse color theme for the domino designer.

http://www.intec.co.uk/update-site-for-eclipse-coloor-themes/

first I had the same proxy problem like you, but this guide helps me, perhaps you to.